# Android Media player OncompletionListener Play Next song but not the second song

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer, android-studio-2.2

I have an App with a music Player, i am using the @override Method OnCompletionListener to listen when the music is complete and pass to the next song, the bellow code works, but in the second song when finish OncompletionListener is not calling Again and the music stop when finish, how pass to the next song continually?

**OnCompletionListener**

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                              NextSong();
                          }
                      });
```

**NextSong** **Method**

```
public void NextSong (){

    num = posicion++;

    if (MainActivity.num <= MainActivity.listaArray.size() - 2) {

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(archivosMp3[num + 1]));
        mmr.setDataSource(String.valueOf(archivosMp3[num + 1]));  

        mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer.create(Servicio_Reproductor.this, MainActivity.uri);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not able to get your question. What do you mean by second song?

Comment: I have a playlist, i play a song, when song finish onCompletionListener is called and the next song of the Playlist start, but when this song finish not continue passing to next song. i think that Oncompletion listener is not calling again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    public class MediaplayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener 
    {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        .
        .
        .
         mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer.create(Servicio_Reproductor.this, MainActivity.uri);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah dude!! Thanks alot, your Code works perfectlly! :D